# How to check for incorrect login attempt?

Tags: authentication, linux

What is the linux system command to check for an incorrect user login attempt?

Comment: I basically want to write a script that will check the log file and email me every time an invalid user attempts to login.

Comment: Okay, that's a different question - as kce says, Fail2Ban is the most common way, there's also DenyHosts - http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

`faillog` - That command reads (usually) /var/log/faillog and lists failed logins.  Use `man faillog` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You might also find `/var/log/auth.log` interesting; it will contain more authentication information as well as log the successful login attempts.

A sample from my workstation:

```
pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=hostname.local  user=username
Jun 20 15:12:38 hostname sshd[8647]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): getting password (0x00000388)
Jun 20 15:12:38 hostname sshd[8647]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): pam_get_item returned a password
Jun 20 15:12:39 hostname sshd[8647]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): request wbcLogonUser failed: WBC_ERR_AUTH_ERROR, PAM error: PAM_USER_UNKNOWN (10), NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, Error message was: No such user
Jun 20 15:12:40 hostname[8647]: Failed password for user from $IP_ADDRESS port 36014 ssh2
```

You can see sshd (through PAM) tries to authenicate me against the Domain Controller, fails and then attempts against the local user accounts (where I promptly mistype my password).

**EDIT:** I just saw your comment. Take a look at [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which will probably do what you want. No need to reinvent the wheel and all that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the lastb command.....to ensure its proper operation make sure you create /var/log/btmp owned by root:root with perms 600.  You can see the man page for lastb for more information.